# List of Azure ACS Apps and Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

Anyone know a way to get a list of apps registered with Azure ACS (via AppRegNew) and how to get the permissions granted to those apps?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you do not already have the Azure ACS PowerShell module installed, do so by running `Install-Module -Name Acs.Namespaces`.

List your ACS Namespaces by executing `Get-AcsNamespace`

For each listed namespace, navigate to `https://<namespace>.accesscontrol.windows.net`, then under **Trust relationships**, select **Relying party applications** to see the list of ACS apps

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I'm not looking for information on Azure AD apps, I'm looking for information on Azure ACS apps (i.e. those registered using AppRegNew.aspx)

Comment: I apologize, I assume you had intended Azure AD apps since Azure ACS was deprecated more than two years ago.  I assume your tenant was grandfathered in?  I have updated my answer for ACS.